# Trying to Batch Merge MP3 Audio and MP4 Video files

Tags: audio, video, batch, mp3, mp4

This is what I got so far...

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do _ffmpeg -i ("*.mp3") -c copy "__newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

But doesnt quite work...

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c copy output.mkv
```

Trying to modify the above which merges audio/video without reencoding

Ive got about 2000 files to do. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: What should happen if the video is longer than the audio or the audio is longer then the vídeo?

Comment: Its not. I actually pulled them from the ultrasingstar catelog... Id just like to recombine the files.

Comment: Antônio made a good point, can you give more information about how the files are structured inside the folders?

Comment: Just a set of files. All with the same name.

AAAA.mp4
AAAA.mp3
BBBB.mp4
BBBB.mp3 etc

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be something like this, but you haven't provided suficient information in your question, like would you like to merge 1 mp3 with every 2000 videos that you have, or do you want to merge 1000 audio with 1000 videos?

If you want to merge one audio with every video it would be something like this:

```
for %%a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "input.mp3" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy "%%~na_modified%~xa"
```

Comment: It would be 1000 audio and 1000 videos

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the videos and audios having the same name except for the file extension and they beeing contained in the same folder:

for %%a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%~na.mp3" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy "%%~na_modified%%~xa"

Comment: This is working good! Thank you for the help. Much appreciated!